# question about methodology to solve equation in sage

Tags: variables, equation, sage

So im trying to solve this equation: 3g - 2h = 1 in sage

by finding the value of both variables so that the  equation  is 1

by hand its g= 1 h=-1
this is what i have so far

```
 var('g,h')
    E = 3*g-2*h 
    1 == 3*g - 2*h 
    solve(E,c,d)
```

Comment: Your question is vague and needs further explanation to determine exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is as follows.

Define the symbolic variables `g` and `h`:

```
sage: g, h = SR.var('g, h')
```

Define the equation `E` as

```
sage: E = 3*g - 2*h == 1
```

Solve `E` in terms for `g` and `h`:

```
sage: solve([E], [g, h])
[[g == 2/3*r1 + 1/3, h == r1]]
```

This returns a list of solutions
containing a single solution, which is
a list of possible values for `g` and `h`.

The solution returned involves a real parameter
(denoted by `r1` here), and `g` and `h` are
expressed in terms of this parameter.

One can also get solutions as dictionaries:

```
sage: sols = solve([E], [g, h], solution_dict=True)
sage: sols
[{g: 2/3*r3 + 1/3, h: r3}]
sage: sol = sols[0]
sage: sol
{g: 2/3*r3 + 1/3, h: r3}
```

Recover the values of `g` and `h` in the solution:

```
sage: sol[g]
2/3*r3 + 1/3
sage: sol[h]
r3
```

Give a Python name to that parameter

```
sage: r3, = sol[h].variables()
sage: r3
r3
```

Substitute some values:

```
sage: sol[g].subs({r3: 1}), sol[h].subs({r3: 1})
(1, 1)
sage: sol[g].subs({r3: -1}), sol[h].subs({r3: -1})
(-1/3, -1)
sage: sol[g].subs({r3: -2}), sol[h].subs({r3: -2})
(-1, -2)
sage: sol[g].subs({r3: 3}), sol[h].subs({r3: 3})
(7/3, 3)
sage: sol[g].subs({r3: 4}), sol[h].subs({r3: 4})
(3, 4)
```